# If $I_1=\int_0^xe^{zx-z^2}dz$ and $I_2=\int_0^xe^{-z^2/4}dz$ then prove that $I_1=e^{x^2/4}I_2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> If $I_1=\int_0^xe^{zx-z^2}dz$ and $I_2=\int_0^xe^{-z^2/4}dz$ then prove that $I_1=e^{x^2/4}I_2$

$$
I_1=\int_0^xe^{zx-z^2}dz\quad\&\quad I_2=\int_0^xe^{-z^2/4}dz\\
I'_1(x)=\int_0^xze^{zx-z^2}dz\\
I'_2(x)=e^{-x^2/4}
$$

How do I prove this, any use applying the Leibniz rule here ?

Comment: $I_1'$ is a bit more complicated than what you have. You have to use the chain rule when the variable with respect to which you are differentiating shows up both in the limits and in the integrand. Your $I_2'$ is correct. But showing the derivatives are the same suffers from the issue that if you show $I_1'=I_2',$ you must then show that the constants of integration are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete the square:
$$zx-z^2=-z^2+zx+\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{4}=-\left(z^2-zx+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)+\frac{x^2}{4}=-(z-x/2)^2+\frac{x^2}{4}. $$
Then 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x e^{zx-x^2}\,dz&=\int_0^xe^{x^2/4}e^{-(z-x/2)^2}\,dz\\
&=e^{x^2/4}\int_0^xe^{-(z-x/2)^2}\,dz.
\end{align*}
What remains is to show that
$$\int_0^xe^{-(z-x/2)^2}\,dz=\int_0^xe^{-z^2/4}\,dz. $$
We substitute $u/2=z-x/2.$ Then $du/2=dz $ and the integral on the left becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-x}^{x}e^{-u^2/4}\,du=\int_0^{x}e^{-u^2/4}\,du, $$
and you are done.